# Trying to change the screen resolution of my Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have created a new Virtual Machine and installed `Ubuntu` on it, but now I'm 100% needing a bigger screen resolution, to actually get the work that I need finished, finished.

Here is what I've got right now: [link](http://prntscr.com/h1r2fp). When trying to change the resolution, the drop-down menu is empty and I can't choose a different resolution.

Anyone who could help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try running these commands:

```
xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode VGA1 1440x900_60.00

xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1440x900_60.00
```

Comment: Try running xrandr -q first then.

Comment: It tells me: 
"Failed to get size of gamma for output default 
screen 0: minimum 1152 x 864, current 1152 x 864, maximum 1152 x 865
 default connected primary 1152x864+0+0 0mm x 0mm". What do I do?

Comment: Thats problematic... Yeah it seems your screen only accepts 1152x864. Normally you could change the resolution with those commands as i pointed above. However if even xandr -q says that the only resolution your allowed is 1152x864. Then you need a new screen.